# Matrix of Powers of Linear Operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\Mat}{\operatorname{Mat}}$
This may seem like a trivial fact but how would you show that:

Suppose $T \in L(V)$ Then $\Mat(T^n) = \Mat(T) \cdots \Mat(T)$ where there are $n$ of them?

Comment: Induction (.......)

Comment: Base case n = 2 doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: How would you define applying the transformation $T^2$? as applying $T$ twice?

Comment: Do not have standard definition but idea is like if: $T(x,y) = (y,x)$ then $T^2(x,y) = T(y,x) = T(x,y)$

Comment: nvm resolved. pg 51 of Axler gave the definition $M(TS) = M(T)M(S)$

Comment: Do you know what it means for a linear operator $T$ to e given (in a certain basis that you forgot to mention) by a certain matrix? Write that down, and then see what it means to apply $T$ twice in succession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $M=(m_{ij})$ is the matrix representation of $T$ under a certain basis $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
T^2(v_j)
&= T\left(T(v_j)\right)\\
&= T\left( \sum_{k=1}^n m_{kj}v_k \right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n m_{kj} T(v_k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n m_{kj} \sum_{i=1}^n m_{ik} v_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{k=1}^n m_{ik} m_{kj}\right) v_i.
\end{align*}
Since $\sum_{k=1}^n m_{ik} m_{kj}$ is, by definition, the $(i,j)$-th entry of $M^2$, the result follows.